# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport.isMtls()'

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have the following error:

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport.isMtls()'

[image]

I have tried cleaning the Google API libraries but I can't solve it.

[image]

[image]

I want to use OAuth 2.0 for server to server applications.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.